# sorting a file on column 1

Tags: sort

I have a file in this format which I want to sort

```
RNU2-46P    0
RNU2-2P 9
RNU2-63P    5
RNU2-36P    6
RNU2-56P    8
RNU2-17P    0
```

I want to sort it on column 1 and get this output

```
RNU2-2P 9
RNU2-17P    0
RNU2-36P    6
RNU2-46P    0
RNU2-56P    8
RNU2-63P    5
```

I tried the sort command but it is not sorting the way I want.
Help!!

Thanks

Comment: Does every line begin with `RNU2-`?

Comment: yes every line begins with RNU2-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a good enough approximation?

```
cat garble
RNU2-46P    0
RNU2-2P 9
RNU2-63P    5
RNU2-36P    6
RNU2-56P    8
RNU2-17P    0



sort -t'-' -k2n garble
RNU2-2P 9
RNU2-17P    0
RNU2-36P    6
RNU2-46P    0
RNU2-56P    8
RNU2-63P    5
```

Comment: HI , this works pretty well, can you explain the 2n part??

Comment: @user3138373 : Sure.  With mixed strings like yours sorting numerically doesn't work. I told sort to consider '-' a field separator, and sort numerically on the 2nd field '-k2n'. Sort will read all numerical values of the field (discarding the P and everything after, since the P and spaces aren't digits).